# How to accept different data types from user in single line of input?

Tags: types

I wanted a method that enables me to take various data types as a single line input code from a user.
The method they taught in school is restrictive.

```
var = input('Enter Something:')
if (var>='0' and var <='0'):
print('Entered variable is an Integer')
elif (var>='a' and var<='z') or (var>='A' and var<='Z'):
print('Entered variable is a string')
else:
print('Entered variable is a special character')
```

This method is very restrictive, i can't check float values, complex numbers, bools etc.

also when taking an input from a user i can't use type() function either, tried my luck with isinstance() too.

So i thought maybe if we had a way to be able to take various data types in a single input code line my life would become easier and i would be able to use type() function easily. i searched about this and found out that apparently python version 2's input() function had this ability to detect various data types while the current one is restricted to strings only.

Comment: You can use regex to identify the incoming input, https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Comment: You can take the input and simply split it.

Answer (score 0):

We can take multiple data types in a single input line by using the eval() function.

Example

```
x, y, z = eval(input("Enter three values: ")) print("x =", x, "y =", y, "z =", z)
```

or

```
var = input('Enter Something:') 
if (var>='0' and var <='0'): 
    print('Entered variable is an Integer') 
elif (var>='a' and var<='z') or (var>='A' and var<='Z'): 
    print('Entered variable is a string') 
else: 
    print('Entered variable is a special character')
```

or

```
#Printing some of the string
var = input('Enter Something:') if (var>='0' and var <='0'): print('Entered variable is an Integer') elif (var>='a' and var<='z') or (var>='A' and var<='Z'): print('Entered variable is a string') else: print('Entered variable is a special character')
```